# WHERE clause on SQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query to return the number of jobs(visits) that a customer availed and the distinct vets he/she has used.

```
SELECT 
customer.users_id AS CustID, 
COUNT(VisitID) AS Jobs, 
COUNT(DISTINCT VetID) AS Resources 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN visit ON customer.users_id = visit.CustID 
GROUP BY customer.users_id
```

When I add a WHERE clause to get count only visits that weren't Rescheduled or Cancelled, my query looks like this.

```
SELECT 
customer.users_id AS CustID, 
COUNT(VisitID) AS Jobs, 
COUNT(DISTINCT VetID) AS Resources 
FROM customer LEFT JOIN visit ON customer.users_id = visit.CustID 
WHERE visit.Status != 'Cancelled' AND visit.Status != 'ReScheduled' 
GROUP BY customer.users_id
```

However, in this case, I only get the customers who didn't have any cancelled or rescheduled visits, eben though I'm using a left join for customers.

How do I fit in the WHERE clause on this?

Comment: strickt01 has given the correct answer. In an outer-joined record the columns are null, so comparing the column `Status` with `=`, `<>` or `!=` will never be true and thus your outer-joined records get removed and you are where you were with an inner join. I'd like to add that several `AND !=` are more readable with `NOT IN`: `visit.Status NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'ReScheduled')`.

Comment: Agreed re the `NOT IN`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want a `WHERE` clause. This just turns the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. You need an `AND` on the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT customer.users_id AS CustID, COUNT(VisitID) AS Jobs, COUNT(DISTINCT     VetID) AS Resources 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN visit ON customer.users_id = visit.CustID 
AND visit.Status NOT IN('Cancelled','ReScheduled')
GROUP BY customer.users_id
```

Answer (score 2):

When we add a where clause with a `left outer join`,it behaves like an `inner join`, where the filter is applied after the `ON` clause. Try after replacing `where` with `AND` clause

```
SELECT customer.users_id AS CustID, COUNT(VisitID) AS Jobs, COUNT(DISTINCT VetID)  AS Resources 
FROM customer 
LEFT outer JOIN visit 
ON (customer.users_id = visit.CustID) 
AND visit.Status != 'Cancelled' 
AND visit.Status != 'ReScheduled' 
GROUP BY customer.users_id
```